# Why is that return document.getElementsByClassName is working and getElementbyId is not in Watir?

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have this line of codes:

```
puts @browser.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0]').html
```

it works, it display the HTML tags in my page source..
But when I try it with the other fields using this one:

```
puts @browser.execute_script('return document.getElementById("street")[0]').innerHTML
```

and also this line of code:

```
puts @browser.execute_script('return document.getElementById("street")[0]').html
```

I've got an error that says:
: NoMethodError: undefined method `innerHTML' for nil:NilClass
Why is that, getting an element using Class name is working while getting element using Id is not?

And Another question is, Is there any possibility that we can get the line number of the page source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("street")[0]
```

Does not return an array of HTML elements, it returns just a single element.

So just use without `[0]`

```
puts @browser.execute_script('return document.getElementById("street").innerHTML')
```

Comment: I already ommited that one.. but there's still an error.. innerHTML is undefined?

Comment: The reason for this is that as defined in the standard, valid html will only have a single element within a page with a given id value.  Hence the method is named in the singular and returns one element.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
puts @browser.execute_script('return document.getElementById("street")[0]').innerHTML
```

to:

```
puts @browser.execute_script('return document.getElementById("street")').innerHTML
```

getElementById retruns an object or null see [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Answer (score 1):

As the name `getElementById`says it return just one element, because ID's should given once. getElement**s**ByClassName, returns an array of elements, because classes can used multiple times. So just remove the `[0]`